# Search rownames with vector and report vector of row numbers

Tags: r

I want to used a vector of values to search the rownames of a dataframe.  I want the code to return a vector of row numbers associated with the rownames of interest.  In the example below, if I provided `c("GeneA","GeneC","GeneF")` I would want `c(1,3,6)` returnd

The code I provide below reports a single rownumber from a single rowname.  I haven't figured out a way to provide multiple searches and the search results I come up with only use a single search value.

|  | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GeneA | 81.06 | -1.59 | 0.29 |
| GeneB | 174.78 | -1.57 | 0.28 |
| GeneC | 124.62 | -1.49 | 0.22 |
| GeneD | 232.72 | -1.45 | 0.25 |
| GeneE | 52.41 | -1.41 | 0.33 |
| GeneF | 29.47 | -1.40 | 0.39 |

```r
which(rownames(df) == "GeneB")
[1] 2
```

Comment: `which(rownames(df) %in% c("GeneA","GeneC","GeneF"))`

Comment: This worked but it does not keep the order of the search.  It rearranges the values from smallest to largest.  So if I were to search with c("GeneF","GeneC","GeneA"), the results would still be c(1,3,6) but in this case I would want c(6,3,1).  I oversimplified my dataset and didn't capture this detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `match`

```
match(c("GeneA","GeneC","GeneF"), rownames(df))
```